# VPN IKEv2 Remote Access not access another hosts

Tags: vpn, pfsense

VPN IKEv2 Remote Access not access another hosts

Hello, I have a problem.
I have an IKEv2 VPN for users.

Everyone connects normally to this VPN.
I configured for users to have a 192.168.2.0/24 subnet.
And phase 2 tunnels place for a LAN subnet, which is 192.168.1.0/24.

I released it on the IPSec firewall to get anything in and out (to try to see if it worked).
With this release, I can ping pfsense but I cannot ping any other machine on the sub lan 192.168.1.0/24.

I looked in the firewall log and it shows that it got there and was released.

Could someone help me?

Comment: phase 2 tunnels place for a LAN subnet, which is 192.168.1.0/24.  <-- Are you sure this is correct for your VPN?  IKE VPN normally uses Phase 1 and Phase 2 for encryption and security. Tunnel setup is outside of that.

Comment: As far as I know the tunnels are built in Phase 2.
But I cannot place users on the same subnet as the LAN, it is necessary to separate the subnet from remote access to the LAN VPN.
Virtual Address Pool: 192.168.2.0/24 | LAN: 192.168.1.0/24.
In Mobile Clients I configured the "Virtual Address Pool" = 192.168.2.0/24. In Phase 2 I put "Local Network" = LAN.

When user connects I can ping 192.168.1.10 (which is the pfsense server)
But any other 192.168.1. * Host doesn't work.

Comment: Any VPN I have use, tunnels are outside of Phases (security).  Basic tunnel setup permits different subnets assuming the outside IP addresses are different.

Comment: Friend tell me where do you configure the tunnels?  Without pfsense?  Because in any documentation of pfsense it is in Phase 2. Could you tell me where you define the IPSec tunnels?

Comment: External IP, local group, tunnels,  phases,  tunnels, other local group, other external IP.

Comment: I'm not talking about any VPN technology or programs.  I'm having a problem with one that is prsense and I configure any tunnel through the configuration in phase 2.

Comment: In any of these places I configure tunnel for IPSec is that it?

Comment: I drew a text diagram of where tunnels are. To give you more, I would have to place an answer